# Change line color in area-spline chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm creating an Area-spline chart using Highcharts library. I have specified a `linear-gradient` for the background of the area chart.

I cannot find a way to change the line's color. i.e, the line running along the top of the chart.

Here's the link to the code.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6z409h5u/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `series.lineColor` directly, or `plotOptions.areaspline.lineColor` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.areaspline.lineColor)) in general.

For example ([JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/6z409h5u/3/)):

```
plotOptions: {
  areaspline: {
    lineColor: 'pink'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

```
series: [{
lineColor:'#000',
 color: {
   linearGradient: {
     x1: 0,
     x2: 0,
     y1: 0,
     y2: 1
   },
   stops: [
     [0, '#ffe1c6'],
     [1, '#ffffff']
   ]
 },
 data: [12, 25, 18, 45, 35, 60, 48, 32, 48, 24, 56]
```

}]

I put lineColor inside the attibute called series. Try and tell me.

Comment: Thank you so much !